# Changing laravel remember_token field to something else

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

For my project i use the Auth login, everything works fine until i try to logout with :

```
  Auth::logout();
```

I use a custom fieldname herrinerToken instead of the default remember_token. In my model/user.php i edited the function getRememberToken() to:

```
 public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'herrinerToken';
}
```

when i try to logout now i get the message:

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `gebruikers` set `herrinerToken` = a3eYy1IIbX1FfPhPgmYNTNLwkE7A43vgqwpSU2B5b3EFNHl0ayYF1vUSGCbc, `remember_token` = a3eYy1IIbX1FfPhPgmYNTNLwkE7A43vgqwpSU2B5b3EFNHl0ayYF1vUSGCbc where `id` = 6**)

So it looks like it tries tu update both remember_token and herrinerToken but i only want to update the herinner_token field. What do i need to adjust to only update the herrinerToken field and not the remember_token field ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a `herrinerToken` column instead of `remember_token` column to your users (or equivalent) database table.

You should use along with that the following snippet:

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->herrinerToken;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->herrinerToken = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'herrinerToken';
}
```

Comment: The problem is the SQL error in his question clearly shows "remember_token" in the query - so Laravel is ignoring that he set "herrinerToken" as the name.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this. It turns out that the field name 'remember_token' is actually hard coded into the `DatabaseUserProvider` - so even if you change it in your model - Laravel will still look for 'remember_token' if you are using the Database Auth Driver.

You need to switch to the Eloquent auth driver. It seems as though you are using Eloquent for your user model anyway - so there should be now issue switching.

Change the following setup in your `app/config/auth.php` file that Eloquent is being used - that should fix this issue for now:

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'eloquent',
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Laravel has changed since this was originally answered, but there is a simple answer:

In your **User.php** file add:

```
protected $rememberTokenName = 'myTokenField';
```

As far as I can tell this value is used by the `getRememberTokenName` method and therefore propagates to the rest of the code.

As  [Laurence](/users/1317935/laurence) indicated there may be a problem with the Database Auth driver which seems to use a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `remember_key` column instead of `remember_token` column to your users (or equivalent) database table.

You should use along with that the following snippet:

```
  public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_key;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_key = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_key';
}
```