# Laravel logout remember token error

Tags: laravel, token, logout

This time I'm trying to do logout user... I'm pretty sure that my routing and controllers are good, but I don't know why I have error looks like this ( of course when I'm trying to logout ):

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list'
```

This is my method in controller :

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

My logout is a link in view... What is wrong?

Comment: Can you check your users table if it has `remember_token` column?

Comment: My table name is shopUsers, but I changed it in conf to auth ( maybe here is problem?). And I don't have column in my table shopUsers like "remember_token" -> I have to admit thaht I really don't know what it is "remember token" and why is error like this

Comment: Table which is being used for auth should have `remember_token` column

Comment: Ok, so I should add this column - but can you explain me why? And what is it for? I'm just starting programmer and please understand me that I don't know everything yet, I learn.

Comment: And this remember_token is what? int? should I add this column last in table?

Comment: Laravel uses remember_token column for session. every time you log out, this column value will be updated

Comment: You can add it anywhere in table, you can use string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144935/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-wenus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For logout to work in laravel you should add `remember_token` column in your users table. or whatever table you are using for auth

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and reading about [The User Provider Contract](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#the-user-provider-contract), I saw something is also the answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704367/changing-laravel-remember-token-field-to-something-else) in StackOverflow:

As User class inherit from Authenticatable, The Authenticatable class uses the AuthenticatableContract, and implements the methods for getting and setting Tokens for users.

So, a simple solution is to overwrite (or to implement) these methods in your User class (or equivalent):

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'token';
}
```

You can replace the 'token' and use whatever word that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add functions on Auth/LoginController:

```
function get_guard(){
        if(Auth::guard('web')->check()){
            return "web";
        }
        elseif(Auth::guard('manager')->check()){
            return "manager";
        }
        elseif(Auth::guard('client')->check()){
            return "client";
        }
        return "web";
    }

    public function logout(){
        $guard = $this->get_guard();
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin': Auth::guard('admin')->logout(); break;
            case 'web' : Auth::guard('web')->logout(); break;
            default : Auth::guard('web')->logout(); break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route("login"));
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).